# Electron CORS Issues with External Sites

Tags: electron, cors, content-security-policy

When loading certain sites in electron via `BrowserWindow.loadURL()` I see all sorts of CORS errors and 403's. If I load the same URL in chrome, I get none.

I have tried various user agents thinking that might be the issue to no avail.
Also tried electron versions 18-24 as there was a point in the past where Peacock, specifically, did not give an error (v18) but post a cookies/cache purge now it does.

Here is a simple example using Peacock since they are particularly lousy with errors:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.peacocktv.com/watch/home')
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```

Same URL in chrome, no issues at all.
As you can see I am not doing anything exotic in the above example. Just loading a web page. The errors read like it's a problem with the site trying to load external content but if that was the case I would expect to see the same issues in another browser.

```
Some resources are blocked because their origin is not listed in your site's Content Security Policy (CSP). Your site's CSP is allowlist-based, so resources must be listed in the allowlist in order to be accessed.
```

EDIT: Yes, I should have noted some errors are CSP and others are CORS. I get some failed calls saying blocked(CSP) and others as 403. The blurb above is just an example.